# Quickly processing a string

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, optimization

I have an input string which I will use to build an output string. The output string is much the same as the input string but has some slight changes along the way, depending on if we hit a certain characters in the input. The code looks like this

```
outputTree(std::ostream& o, const char* input) {
    size_t len = strlen(input);
    int indent = 0;
    string output;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < input_len; i++) {
        if(input[i] == '(') {
            indent++;
            output.append(1,'\n');
            for(int j = 0; j < indent; j++) {
                output.append("    ");
            }
        }
        if(input[i] == ')') {
            output.append(1,'\n');
            for(int j = 0; j < indent; j++) {
                output.append("    ");
            }
            indent--;
        }
        output.append(1,input[i]);
    }
    o << output << endl;
}
```

While this works, doing it character by character is pretty slow. Can anyone recommend some better approaches to this (pref with standard features, ie no boost)?

Comment: If the code works, then I suggest you ask for a review on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: As a quick suggestion the part `for(int j = 0; j < indent; j++) {
                output.append("    ");
}` Can be moved to a separate function

Comment: What for do you write to `output`? Write directly to `o`, much better. Moreover, you could as well read directly from an `istream`.

Comment: `is pretty slow` - how did you measure? Did you try an optimized build?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a [codereview.se].

Comment: You may want to explain in words what your code actually does. Reading a brief clear description is generally much faster and easier than inferring that from the code itself.

Comment: Call `output.reserve(len);` can improve performance.

Comment: @megabyte1024 but output apparently would be longer in most cases.

Comment: Use `ostream::write()` instead of `operator<<` because unformatted output is faster. Using `string::find_first_of("()")` may also be faster. But all of this is only guesswork, use profiler to determine bottlenecks.

Comment: I wouldn't expect huge performance improvements to be possible here. Some things may be faster than others, but at the end of the day you'll still need to read, check and write every character. If you're trying to print that to the console, that's likely a bigger bottleneck than the actual string construction you're doing in this function. Note that `output` is entirely (logically) redundant, as you can write directly to the output stream, but actual performance may tell a different story.

Comment: @enedil, it is obvious, but the `reserve` call potentially reduces number of memory re-allocations. Please drop attention that I wrote *can*.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what "pretty slow" means and how much improvement you expect. The algorithm you have is an efficient O(N) algorithm. The only thing you can do is trying to optimise individual operations, but then again I am not sure what kind of optimisations is the compiler doing.

One thing you could do is get rid of the inner loops that write the indentation string as many times is needed by the level of indentation (your `indent` variable). So instead of writing a newline and then execute the `for` loop, you can perform just one append that has the newline concatenated with the right amount of indentation. If you can set a limit to the depth of your indentation (say 10 levels deep) you can then create an array that has all 10 different indentation strings (all strings starting with a newline).

Another thing you can try is to use [std::string::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) to find the occurrences of '(' and ')' and do string copies up to these markers, instead of copying character by character.

Finally, note that your code might not behave as you want it, if the input is not as expected. Notice what will happen if you first encounter a ')' without having a corresponding '('.